# configuring two domains in same server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I am trying to configure two domains in same server, but i am getting with "**the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive"**

Below is my Apache2 config file

```
<VirtualHost 88.80.223.163:80>


        ServerAdmin admin@lumiin.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/lumiin 
        ServerName www.lumiin.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        ServerPath /var/www/lumiin
        DirectoryIndex index.html

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 88.80.223.163:80>


        ServerAdmin info@appideas.biz
        DocumentRoot /var/www/lumiin/appideas 
        ServerName appideas.biz
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        ServerPath /var/www/lumiin/appideas
        DirectoryIndex home.html

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Kind regards 
Karthick

Comment: Hmm maybe you need you need a NameVirtualHost directive? Seriously which part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: Second part domain is unclear, I have changed the ip to domain name. Inspite of that i am getting the same error

Answer (score 13):

The Apache documentation for [Name Based Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) is excellent, you should take a moment to read through it.

> the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive

You need to supply a [`NameVirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive

```
NameVirtualHost 88.80.223.163:80
```

should do the trick.